# Why I got 422 unprocessable content when I try to reset password?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, post, reset-password, http-status-code-422

Hello everyone I'm on resetting password with laravel and reactJs
Actually when I try to reset password I always get error 422: {password: ["The password confirmation does not match."]}. But I'm sure the two passwords are the same
this is the function in backend:

```
  public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', RulesPassword::defaults()],
        ]);

        $status = Password::reset(
            $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
            function ($user) use ($request) {
                $user->forceFill([
                    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                    'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
                ])->save();

                $user->tokens()->delete();

                event(new PasswordReset($user));
            }
        );

        if ($status == Password::PASSWORD_RESET) {
            return response([
                'message'=> 'Password reset successfully'
            ]);
        }

        return response([
            'message'=> __($status)
        ], 500);

    }


}
```

this is my frontend :

```
const ResetPasswordBasic = () => {
  const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPass] = useState('');
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [password_confirmation, setCPass] = useState('');



  const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('token', token);
    formData.append('pasword_confirmation', password_confirmation);


    axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/reset-password`, formData).then(res => {

     res.data
    })
  }
  if (!isUserLoggedIn()) {

    return (
      <div className='auth-wrapper auth-basic px-2'>
        <div className='auth-inner my-2'>
          <Card className='mb-0'>
            <CardBody>
              <Link className='brand-logo' to='/' onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
                <svg viewBox='0 0 139 95' version='1.1' height='28'>
                  <defs>
                    <linearGradient x1='100%' y1='10.5120544%' x2='50%' y2='89.4879456%' id='linearGradient-1'>
                      <stop stopColor='#000000' offset='0%'></stop>
                      <stop stopColor='#FFFFFF' offset='100%'></stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                    <linearGradient x1='64.0437835%' y1='46.3276743%' x2='37.373316%' y2='100%' id='linearGradient-2'>
                      <stop stopColor='#EEEEEE' stopOpacity='0' offset='0%'></stop>
                      <stop stopColor='#FFFFFF' offset='100%'></stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                  </defs>
                  <g id='Page-1' stroke='none' strokeWidth='1' fill='none' fillRule='evenodd'>
                    <g id='Artboard' transform='translate(-400.000000, -178.000000)'>
                      <g id='Group' transform='translate(400.000000, 178.000000)'>
                        <path
                          d='M-5.68434189e-14,2.84217094e-14 L39.1816085,2.84217094e-14 L69.3453773,32.2519224 L101.428699,2.84217094e-14 L138.784583,2.84217094e-14 L138.784199,29.8015838 C137.958931,37.3510206 135.784352,42.5567762 132.260463,45.4188507 C128.736573,48.2809251 112.33867,64.5239941 83.0667527,94.1480575 L56.2750821,94.1480575 L6.71554594,44.4188507 C2.46876683,39.9813776 0.345377275,35.1089553 0.345377275,29.8015838 C0.345377275,24.4942122 0.230251516,14.560351 -5.68434189e-14,2.84217094e-14 Z'
                          id='Path'
                          className='text-primary'
                          style={{ fill: 'currentColor' }}
                        ></path>
                        <path
                          d='M69.3453773,32.2519224 L101.428699,1.42108547e-14 L138.784583,1.42108547e-14 L138.784199,29.8015838 C137.958931,37.3510206 135.784352,42.5567762 132.260463,45.4188507 C128.736573,48.2809251 112.33867,64.5239941 83.0667527,94.1480575 L56.2750821,94.1480575 L32.8435758,70.5039241 L69.3453773,32.2519224 Z'
                          id='Path'
                          fill='url(#linearGradient-1)'
                          opacity='0.2'
                        ></path>
                        <polygon
                          id='Path-2'
                          fill='#000000'
                          opacity='0.049999997'
                          points='69.3922914 32.4202615 32.8435758 70.5039241 54.0490008 16.1851325'
                        ></polygon>
                        <polygon
                          id='Path-2'
                          fill='#000000'
                          opacity='0.099999994'
                          points='69.3922914 32.4202615 32.8435758 70.5039241 58.3683556 20.7402338'
                        ></polygon>
                        <polygon
                          id='Path-3'
                          fill='url(#linearGradient-2)'
                          opacity='0.099999994'
                          points='101.428699 0 83.0667527 94.1480575 130.378721 47.0740288'
                        ></polygon>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </svg>
                <h2 className='brand-text text-primary ms-1'>BMS</h2>
              </Link>
              <CardTitle tag='h4' className='mb-1'>
                Reset Password 
              </CardTitle>
              <CardText className='mb-2'>Your new password must be different from previously used passwords</CardText>
              <Form className='auth-reset-password-form mt-2' onSubmit={login}>

                <div className='mb-1'>
                  <Label className='form-label' for='email'>
                    Email
                  </Label>
                  <Input type='email' className='input-group-merge' id='email' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} autoFocus />
                </div>
                
                <div className='mb-1'>
                  <Label className='form-label' for='token'>
                    Token
                  </Label>
                  <Input type='token' className='input-group-merge' id='token' onChange={(e) => setToken(e.target.value)} autoFocus />
                </div>
                <div className='mb-1'>
                  <Label className='form-label' for='password'>
                    New Password
                  </Label>
                  <InputPassword className='input-group-merge' id='password' name='password' onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)} autoFocus />
                </div>
                <div className='mb-1'>
                  <Label className='form-label' for='password_confirmation'>
                    Confirm Password
                  </Label>
                  <InputPassword className='input-group-merge' id='password_confirmation' name='password_confirmation' onChange={(e) => setCPass(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <Button color='primary' block>
                  Set New Password
                </Button>
              </Form>
              <p className='text-center mt-2'>
                <Link to='/pages/login-basic'>
                  <ChevronLeft className='rotate-rtl me-25' size={14} />
                  <span className='align-middle'>Back to login</span>
                </Link>
              </p>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    )

  }
  else {
    return <Redirect to='/' />
  }
}
export default ResetPasswordBasic
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The code looks fine to me... You'll have to do some debugging on your end to figure out why validation is failing. `Log::debug($request->input())` or `dd($request->input())`; both should show `password` and `password_confirmation` fields; see if they do are indeed different.

Comment: @TimLewis when I tested with postman the code is woking fine but when I tried to consume the api I got the error 422

Comment: What does Postman have to do with anything? Postman isn't using your React code, so all that proves is that you have an error somewhere in that code . That is why I'm suggesting you add some logging to your API, so you can view and determine _why_. Or some debugging in your React code to ensure your values are what is expected.

Comment: @TimLewis yes that's exactly what I wanted to explain. okey thank's anyway

Answer (score 0):

i tested your code ! and  the button `set New Password` don't trigger any event !

so you must add to your button `type="submit"`

```
       <Button color='primary' type="submit">
             Set New Password
        </Button>
```

Or Directly add the function you want to trigger when user click the button
`<Button onClick={() => login()} ></Button>`

Comment: Url refers to what !

Comment: your api Endpoint ! same as your code , just add header !

Comment: this didn't work :(

Comment: so you have to debug ! in your controller befor `$request->validate([...])` add `Log::info("Request",[$request->all()])` this will wright a line in the end of log file after excuting the code ! you can find the log file in `storage/log` within your laravel App ! there you can check if inputs are correctly sended to your backend from your frontend ! if they are not correct you have to debug your react app by using `console.log(formdata)` just before the axios post

Comment: another way to debug is to comment all the code in your controller and add `return response()->json($request->all());` and  in your frontend `console.log(res.data)`

Comment: I already tried to  log res.data but I didn't get anything in my inspector because the page refreshed automatically and I didn't know the cause... for the backend I tested it by postman and it works and juste put the email, password, cpassword and the token and it works

Comment: answer edited ! please check and tell me if it work

Comment: my problem was in declaring variables . I wrote pasword_confirmation with one s not double. The correct one is password_confirmation I didn't pay attention..Thank's anyway